# Is there anyway to bind events with "if" dependence in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, bind

I wanna know if there is anyway to depend event binding with "if" in Backbone.

For example, if i have user profile model and i want to bind "Send Message" button event only if the attribute "acceptMsgs" sets true.

My current solution is to check it in the event firing, if there is better way, pls correct me.

Comment: ?? why not doing it when event was fired ?

Comment: Thats what im doing right now, i wanna know if there's better way

Comment: hm, i think the best way is to disable the button if "acceptMsgs" is false and activate it when it`s true .. so if it is not needed to fire the event it will be prevented .. !!?

Comment: yes.. does the unnecessary binding affect on the performance?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's a *better* way to do it, but you can use a function that returns a hash for the event hash (and of course in the function you can check for some condition).

For example something along the lines of

```
myView = Backbone.Views.extend({

    events: function () {
      if (someCondition) {
         return { "#someButton click" : "nameOfFunction"}
      }
    }

 //the rest of your view
});
```

Alternatively you can forgo the event hash and bind your events in the initialize method, for example

```
initialize: function (options) {
   if (someCondition) {
     this.$el.on("click", "#someButton", nameOfFunction);
   }
}
```